# Environment variable with command substitution isn't getting set correctly

Tags: ubuntu, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows 10 WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) and trying to get a command working but having trouble with setting an environment variable.

I need to run:

```
export ADB_SERVER_SOCKET=tcp:<variable ip here>:5037
```

Since in this case the IP that needs to be replaced needs to be from windows this is the final command I came up with:

```
export ADB_SERVER_SOCKET=tcp:$(cmd.exe /C ipconfig | grep "IPv4" | awk 'NR==1{print $14}'):5037
```

In this case the `cmd.exe` command prints out:

```
cmd.exe /C ipconfig | grep "IPv4" | awk 'NR==1{print $14}'
192.168.0.11
```

However if I check what the variable is after running it I get:

```
echo "$ADB_SERVER_SOCKET"
:503792.168.0.11
```

I've tried adding quotation marks around the entire thing as well, but the output always seems the same. I think it's replacing tcp:1 with :5037 for whatever reason.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Looks like the windows command's output has a trailing <CR> (\r, 0x0D, ^M) character that makes the line fold back and continue at pos 1.

Comment: Should I append `tr -d $'\r'` to the windows command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [RudiC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/303610/rudic) mentions correctly in the comments:

> ... the windows command's output has a trailing  (\r, 0x0D, ^M) character that makes the line fold back and continue at pos 1.

[Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) (`CR`) and [Line Feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (`LF`) are from the times of typewriters: `CR` would cause the slide (carriage) to return back to its starting position (far left), while `LF` would cause the paper roll to feed in the next line.

Windows line endings are always `CRLF`, while Unix line endings are `LF`.

The extra `CR` is causing the cursor to jump back to the first position, overwriting what was previously there.

If you remove that (with `tr` for example), you get the expected output.

```
echo tcp:$(cmd.exe /C ipconfig | grep "IPv4" | awk 'NR==1{print $14}' | tr -d $'\r'):5037
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `grep` nor the `tr` commands. `awk` can do it all for you (untested as I don't have a windows system):

```
cmd.exe /C ipconfig | awk '/IPv4/ {sub(/\r$/, "", $14); print $14}'
```

Comment: This unfortunately returns two IPV4 values, there must be two coming back from `ipconfig`

Comment: @LeonardoPetrucci you should consider asking `ipconfig` for the correct interface in the first place

Comment: @Panki I'll be honest I had no idea I could do that 

Comment: If you want the first entry only, `exit` after the `print` statement...